# Alternative to std::istream::ignore

Tags: c++, fstream

std::istream::ignore discards characters until one compares equal to delim. Is there an alternative working on strings rather then chars, i.e one that discards strings until one compares equal to the specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to continuously extract a string until you find the right one:

```
std::istringstream iss;
std::string str;
std::string pattern = "find me";

while ( iss >> str && str != pattern ) ;
if (!iss) { /* Error occured */ }
```

This assumes that the strings are delimited with whitespace characters, of course.